# Function return and foreach trouble

Tags: php, function, foreach, return, syntax-error

I have a simple function:

```
function name() {
 extract( myfunction_atts( array(
        'one' => '',  
        'two' => '',  
        ), $atts ) ); 

  /* CODE */

 return $output; /* return dataName(); in second case */
}
```

Now, I want the return to output this code:

```
    $output .= include_once(ADDRESS_CONST."/script.php");
    $output .= $data = data($one); 
    $output .= foreach($data->do($two) as $e) {;
    $output .= $e->info;
    $output .= } ;
```

Gives **syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH**.

So I need a function, the point is:

```
function dataName() {

        /* global $one;
        global $two;
        doesn't work */

        include_once(ADDRESS_CONST."/script.php");
        $data = data($one); 

        foreach($data->do($two) as $e) {;
          $e->info;
        } ;  
}
```

Doesn't "see" $one and $two variables. I'm sure I'm missing something and there's probably an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foreach cannot be assigned like this :

```
$output .= foreach($data->do($two) as $e) {;
$output .= $e->info;
$output .= } ;
```

Instead, what you want is to loop with the `foreach()`, and, inside the loop, assign the current value to your `$output` :

```
foreach ($data->do($two) as $e) {
    $output .= $e->info;
}
```

Basically speaking, [`foreach()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is a control structure : it allows your script to loop ; but that's all : it doesn't return any value by itself.

On the other hand, inside the loop, you can do pertty much whatever you want : the `foreach()` only make sure that this code is executed for each item of your array.

Comment: Oh my, this is brilliant! Checking! :)